# Very peculiar feature selection issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select

One of our ArcMap users is having a feature selection issue that I haven't run into before. I think the issues are all related, but when the user selects one feature, multiple features are being selected. I thought maybe it was the selection tolerance but that wasn't changed.

Then when looking into it a little deeper, I noticed when selecting in open space near the features, ArcMap is selecting the feature even though the selection tool is not near the actual features. As you can see in the image I am showing where I am clicking with the selection tool, and which features are being selected.

[image]
[image]

We are using ArcMap 10.3.1 and the features are stored in an ArcSDE SQL SQL Server 2008 Database .

Comment: What coordinate system is the data in?

Comment: The system of the data and frame is WGS84

Comment: Have you restarted ArcMap and tried to perform the same test?

Comment: Yes, we have restarted his ArcMap quite a few times. He's has been having issues with creating vertices for a couple weeks on certain features, and just today we realized this was the issue.

Comment: I've have had selection issues when the map in one coordinate system and the underlying data is WGS84, have you set a correct transformation? Also try projecting the data to something that is not WGS84, if only for a sanity check.

Comment: Try rebuilding the spatial index on the feature class.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the vales being used for search, and the units of that value. If you think you're searching in meters and the data is n in degrees, a "5" search tolerance is actually 300 nautical miles.

Comment: @Vince I'm not sure what you are referring to. I am not "searching" for anything. The "select tolerance" is in pixels.

Comment: @Hornbydd the map and data are in WGS84. I will try to rebuild the search index.